# Generate all months dynamically between two dates on a table

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like this:

| NAME | INT_VALUE | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 100 | 2013-11-16 | 2014-11-16 |

The goal is to output like this:

| NAME | INT_VALUE | START | END | INTERVAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 100 | 2013-11-16 | 2014-11-16 | 11-2013 |
| One | 100 | 2013-11-16 | 2014-11-16 | 12-2013 |
| One | 100 | 2013-11-16 | 2014-11-16 | 1-2014 |
| One | 100 | 2013-11-16 | 2014-11-16 | 2-2014 |

I've started using this. But I am not really sure how I'd use the START and END dates on the table to determine the start and end to calculate the list of months between.

```
SELECT START, calendar, COUNT(1)
FROM table1 AS t1
    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) AS MONTHS
                ,      TO_DATE(DATEADD(MONTH, MONTHS, '2019-05-01')) AS calendar
                FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount=>80)))
            ON t1.START = calendar
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2, 1
;
```

The goal here is to associate the int value with every month from the beginning to the end of the range.

Comment: Example in docs - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series

Comment: Is this mysql or snowflake, as they have different possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT name, int_value, start, `end`, 
                1 rownum, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%m-%Y') `interval`
         FROM source_table
         UNION ALL
         SELECT name, int_value, start, `end`, 
                1 + rownum, DATE_FORMAT(start + INTERVAL rownum MONTH, '%m-%Y')
         FROM cte
         WHERE start + INTERVAL rownum - 1 MONTH < `end` )
         
SELECT name, int_value, start, `end`, `interval`
FROM cte
ORDER BY rownum;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdd028a7755fdcb8296df2301baeb295

If you do not need in leading zeros in month numbers then use `'%c-%Y'` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

so moving the `range of numbers` out to it's own CTE to separate things, we now have a big list of 80 numbers (it could be bigger).

Then we find the number of months between the start/end and join to that many rows. And do the math to turn the range into the select part:

```
WITH range_of_numbers AS (
    SELECT 
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4())-1 AS rn
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount=>80))
)
SELECT 
    t1.name, 
    t1.int_value, 
    t1.start,
    t1.end,
    DATEADD(MONTH, r.rn, t1.start) as interval
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN range_of_numbers as r
    ON date_diff('month', t1.START, t1.end) <= between r.rn
ORDER BY 2,1,3;
```

Another option is it build a long range DATE table

```
CREATE TABLE dates AS 
SELECT 
     DATEADD(MONTH, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4())-1, '1980-01-01') as month_date
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount=>8000))
```

Then we use [BETWEEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/between.html) to get the inclusive values in the (start,end) range
would become:

```
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN dates as d
    ON d.month_date BETWEEN t1.START AND t1.end
```